# ORA-02199: missing DATAFILE/TEMPFILE clause

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I exported a database and it created a sql file for me with `create` and `insert` but I get an error saying `ORA-02199: missing DATAFILE/TEMPFILE clause`

in `sql plus` I run the sql script and get a bunch of `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` Then i noticed when it creates a table it has `TABLESPACE "LOCALDEV" ;` So I enter `CREATE tablespace LOCALDEV`

Prior to all that I enter `create user localdev identified by localdev;`

and

`grant ALTER SESSION, CREATE SESSION, CREATE DATABASE LINK, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM, CREATE ROLE,CREATE SEQUENCE, CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE TYPE, CREATE VIEW, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to localdev;`

> SQL> create tablespace localdev datafile '/u01/app/localdev.dbf'
>   size 100m;
>
> ```
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/u01/app/localdev.dbf'
> ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
> Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied
> Additional information
> ```

: 1

I get no error until I run the sql script. If I had a BDA to ask I would but do not. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may be stating the obvious but have you checked the ownership of the directory is it oinstall/oracle. It’s been a long time since I worked on oracle but I do remember having to do a chmod and chown on the base directories and their sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

> I exported a database and it created a sql file for me with create and
>   insert but I get an error saying ORA-02199: missing DATAFILE/TEMPFILE
>   clause (bla bla bla)

In my opinion, the very first step you did was wrong. If you wanted to *export* the "database" (I presume it is, actually, a "schema" (i.e. "user")), then you should have done that. Oracle offers **Data Pump** utility, export and import.

If you performed export, you'd take the DMP file with you and import it into another database using import data pump with the `REMAP_TABLLESPACE` parameter which accepts two values: the old, "source" tablespace and the new, "target" tablespace, separated by colon. For example:

```
impdp scott/tiger@new_database REMAP_TABLESPACE=localdev:users DIRECTORY=dump_dir DUMPFILE=scott.dmp
```

**Alternatively**, as you currently have a textual file that contains `CREATE` & `INSERT` statements, why didn't you open it in any text editor and **replaced** the old tablespace name (localdev) with a tablespace name used in your new database (that would be "users" in my `IMPDP` example)?

It takes a few seconds, you run it, everything gets created and you don't have to reinvent the wheel by doing everything you did after the first sentence (that would be *bla bla* part).